# How avoid group by when using Having clause SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my query

```
    select * from [database].[W_work]
 where DATE__CALC is null and ST_ID = 86
 group by ST_ID 
 having MAX(modification_date) < GETDATE()
```

I wanna avoid group by in my query. How can i do it please ? Thank you

Comment: You can't. the `HAVING` clause is there for performing boolean operations against aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you *actually* need here is a windowed aggregate and a CTE or derived table:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {Column List}, --Don't use *, define your columns
           MAX(modification_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ST_ID) AS Max_modification_date
    FROM [database].[W_work] --Do you really have a schema called "database"?
    WHERE DATE__CALC IS NULL
      AND ST_ID = 86)
SELECT {Column List} --Don't use *, define your columns
FROM CTE
WHERE Max_modification_date < GETDATE();
```